# express route parameters not being set

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

I am trying to get route parameters working with express, i have the following code trying to use the colon to define the parameters, if I do just the station id it works `app.get('/:stationId/` but adding on the radius part just doesn't return anything. What am i doing wrong?

```
app.get('/:stationId/asset?radius=:radius', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params.stationId)
    console.log(req.params.radius)

})
```

I know I would be able to change the url to be `app.get('/:stationId/:radius` but i need it in the other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters after the `?` are handled differently:

```js
app.get("/:stationId/asset", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.stationId);
  console.log(req.query.radius);
});
```